# How to send multiple value for one param to mapserver through openlayers (encode_uri)

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, mapserver, mapfile, encode

Here's my filter on Mapserver's Side :

```
PROCESSING "NATIVE_FILTER=(ct in ('%ct%'))"
```

It allows me to select several values for my column. My validation looks like :

```
VALIDATION
    'ct' '^[a-zA-Z\-]+$'    
    'default_ct' 'a'
END
```

On Openlayers side, I get stuck to send several value though. If I do this :

```
var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
   url: 'http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1%20&REQUEST=GetCapabilities',
        serverType: 'mapserver',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'layer','ct':"value1,value2",'TILED': true}
  });
```

My comma is encoded while asking mapserver as you can see on that url :

```
http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1%20&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=later&ct=value1%2Cvalue2&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=-5009377.085697312%2C5009377.085697312%2C-9.313225746154785e-10%2C10018754.171394624
```

My comma has been transcoded in %2C. Is there a way to prevent that, or to solve it?

EDIT : That was actually a validation error. I made the following changes :

```
var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
   url: 'http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1%20&REQUEST=GetCapabilities',
        serverType: 'mapserver',
        params: {'LAYERS': 'layer','ct':"('value1','value2')",'TILED': true}
  });
```

and in my mapfile :

```
VALIDATION
    'ct' '^[a-zA-Z\-\,\\\(\)\']+$'
    'default_ct' 'a'
END
```

As I need to always return something (see [that question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214899/in-operator-in-filter-in-my-mapfile/214921#214921)) my FILTER look like that :

```
PROCESSING "NATIVE_FILTER=((ct in %ct%) or (%ct% in 'a'))"
```

I've got that error :

> msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Error (ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « 'a' »
>   LINE 1: ...ainer','fishing')) or (('container','fishing') in 'a')) and ...

(== Error syntax.)

Comment: Why you are including the "&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1%20&REQUEST=GetCapabilities" in your URL ? it is already generated by default.

Comment: Did you follow this example http://www.ms4w.com/trac/wiki/MapCacheOpenLayers3

Comment: Nop I didn't see it. I removed  "&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1%20&REQUEST=GetCapabilities" and it works. Actually it's not an url encode issue, I updated my question

Comment: try below link, filtering columns cannot be used the way you wrote it.  check this link,  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54947/geoserver-where-clause-filter

Comment: @Shiko I don't think your answers could help me as I can't set a default value because I don't have one. I have to be able to select multiple values at once or all the values. For my ct, I've got 11 values different, I can't "hardwritten" (hardcoded?) them, if I add one in my db it won't be reverberated

Comment: Did you check the answer, i have updated it

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options to filter fields in WMS:
**1) Filter (Encoded XML format) :**

```
 var map, layer, select, hover, control;

    function init(){
        OpenLayers.ProxyHost= "proxy.cgi?url=";
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoom(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Permalink(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()
            ]
        });
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "States WMS/WFS",
            "http://v2.suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/ows",
            {layers: 'usa:states', format: 'image/gif'}
        );
        select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection", {styleMap: 
            new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"])
        });
        hover = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Hover");
        map.addLayers([layer, hover, select]);

        control = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
            protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS.fromWMSLayer(layer),
            box: true,
            hover: true,
            multipleKey: "shiftKey",
            toggleKey: "ctrlKey"
        });
        control.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
            select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
        control.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) {
            select.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
        control.events.register("hoverfeature", this, function(e) {
            hover.addFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
        control.events.register("outfeature", this, function(e) {
            hover.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
        });
        map.addControl(control);
        control.activate();

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.Bounds(-140.444336,25.115234,-44.438477,50.580078).getCenterLonLat(), 3);
    }
```

**Example:**
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/getfeature-wfs.html
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/wfs-filter.js

**2) cql_filter**

```
cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom,%20POINT%20(-74.817265%2040.5296504))
```

**Example:**
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/cql-format.html

**Reference:**
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html

Comment: With : params: {'LAYERS': 'layer','ct':['value1, value2'],'TILED': true}

VALIDATION
 'ct' '.'
 'default_ct' 'a'
   
END

And PROCESSING "NATIVE_FILTER=(ct in ('%ct%') or '%ct%' = 'a')"

(url is : http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=layer&ct=value1%2C%20value2&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=5009377.085697312%2C0%2C10018754.171394624%2C5009377.085697311

Nothing appears, and no error

Comment: ct is a filter or what exactly ?

Comment: My bad I forgot quote betweens value1 et value2 but it doesn't change anything (url is : http://localhost:5000/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/ms4w/apps/tutorial/htdocs/essai.map&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=layer&ct=value1%2Cvalue2&TILED=true&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A3857&STYLES=&BBOX=15028131.257091936%2C-10018754.17139462%2C20037508.342789248%2C-5009377.085697309

Comment: ct is a column on my postgis db. I need to be able to select multiple values for this column (with the in), or display every value if no parameter is given